# Does Python ever stop an infinite "for" loop?

Tags: python

Does python automatically terminate or generate an error for an infinite "for" loop?

for example, would

```
list = [1]

for number in list:
    print (number + 1)
    list.append(number + 1)
```

cause the program to self-terminate or error?

I have tested it a bit, going as far as around 10,000.

Comment: Eventually you'll get a memory error, because the list will be too large.

Comment: Eventually you'll run out of memory for your list and it will throw an exception, but it will not attempt to break the loop for you

Comment: I think what you're asking comes down to a question like this: you know that you can tell Python to 'go forever', and you know it will do what you say, but you *don't* know if at some point a higher-level operating system authority will step in behind you and say, "That's enough!". There are a few reasons it might, but none like "this has simply been running for too long." Search for the term 'preemptive scheduling' to find out more reasons the OS might interrupt your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the program will run forever. It may crash because your call stack is to big (if you use recursion somewhere) or you used to much memory though. Your example will eventually crash.

```
while True:
    pass
```

Will run "forever" with no issues however.

Comment: Well, with the print it probably won't seem frozen

Comment: I think he means it will seem frozen if it hangs since the number is so big

Answer (score 1):

That program will end, but it will be a very long time until it does.  Eventually, you'll run the system out of memory for your list and the program will crash with an error.

Answer (score 1):

It won't unless you specify a range or a limit. The way you currently have it it'll keep going until you get a memory error.

Also, don't use `list` as a variable since it's a reserved function by python.